# Issue of small 1px, 2px spacing , while using border radius ( in all browsers )

Tags: html, css

Here is a screen for the question above http://prntscr.com/66o7rf .
When I use border-radius in parent div and overlap another background with same value of border-radius, there appears a small space ( in screen, white space appears ).
I tried using background in :before and :after , but i don't think is a good way to do it.

Can anybody help with this?

```css
body{
    background: grey;
}
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-top: 160px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.footer {
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check this link https://jsfiddle.net/th293j7L/1/

Answer (score 1):

When you use border-radius in parent div, dont set overflow: hidden to it. And for overlapping div or child div of it add border-radius to it but 2px less than parent div.
Example:

```
div{
background: #fff;
border-radius: 10px;
}

.child{
background: blue;
border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Can I ask how you knew that the OP had used `overflow: hidden` 7 minutes before he had provided any code?

Comment: because i faced the same problem , when i was working on my current project .

Comment: Awesome, same problem and overflow:hiddne was the cause. Thank you very much!